# Exporting Resultset from Java database to Excel using Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, resultset

Help am stucked on this project of exporting from result set to excel..previous solutions here haven't answered my questions but they have helped..here is my code so far it only displays a row in the database.
My Code

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;


public class Plexada2 {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Storeway","root", "");
         Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from Storeway.order");

         HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
         HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("lawix10");


         Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
         int x=0;
         while (rs.next()){
         String crate_id=  rs.getString(2);
         String content=rs.getString(3);
         String Order_type=  rs.getString(4);
         java.sql.Date date= rs.getDate(5);
         String datex= String.valueOf(date);

         row.createCell(0).setCellValue(crate_id);
         row.createCell(1).setCellValue(content);
         row.createCell(2).setCellValue(Order_type);
         row.createCell(3).setCellValue(datex); 

                }
         x+=1;  



        String yemi = "C:\\Users\\lawix10\\Desktop\\testlno9.xls";
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
             fileOut = new FileOutputStream(yemi);
             workbook.write(fileOut);
             fileOut.close();
                }
```

Comment: Where are you creating a new row, every time after iterating though the ResultSet object? Even better you create the headers at row 0 and start creating rows in while loop, iterating using x

Comment: What do you see in excel sheet can you access that location with java program?

Comment: Can you please share what you are getting in the excel sheet? Also if possible please format your above code properly.

Comment: i can see just one row from the database on the excel

Comment: a bit late, but take a look at MemPOI for the future https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ahh its very difficult to inspect your code trying formatting it before you post it and Regarding your query try something like this.

```
try {
    Class.forName("driverName");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "pass");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from tablename");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("lawix10");
    HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("CellHeadName1");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("CellHeadName2");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("CellHeadName3");
    int i = 1;
    while (rs.next()){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("column1")));
        row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("column2"));
        row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("column3"));
        i++;
    }
    String yemi = "g:/test.xls";
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(yemi);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys, this is my first time posting a question, so am not used to the formatting . Thanks

Comment: OMG it worked perfectly..Thanks M.sharma you are a Genious really appreicate..wont mind having your contacts...please can u explain what short does in the code

Comment: Thats basic bro just read the poi doc and see about the classes and methods used in the code and btw you if u got the ans of your question you can accept it as your ans by ticking at the right symbol near the ans.

Comment: Working like a charm, please add workbookclose().

Answer (score 3):

I suggest another solution, taking advantage of [MemPOI](https://firegloves.github.io/MemPOI/) lib.
Take a look:

```
public class Plexada2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Storeway","root", "");
           PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from Storeway.order");
           
           File fileDest = new File("C:\\Users\\lawix10\\Desktop\\testlno9.xls");

           final MempoiReport mempoiReport = 
                MempoiBuilder.aMemPOI()
                    .withFile(fileDest)
                    .addMempoiSheet(new MempoiSheet(prepStmt))
                    .build()
                    .prepareMempoiReport()
                    .get();

           final String file = mempoiReport.getFile();

         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO manage exception
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @firegloves, is it good with large volume of data? converting stored procedure results to excel?

Comment: @AskWarvin yes, it is meant to be used with large volumes of data: it does not use any ORM for that very reason. I didn't try using stored procedures, but the concept is that you have to create your query and then pass to the library a PreparedStatement, so whatever the DBMS returns to the ResultSet is available to MemPOI.

Comment: @firegloves can you update this example? Eclipse warning about deprecated methods

Comment: @erickdeoliveiraleal updated. You can have a look at MemPOI's docs if you need some further explanation of the APIs update

Answer (score 0):

can we have for loop to enter dynamic values into getString()?I tried this, but i couldnt fetch exact result.

My code:
public static void excel(String appDB)
    {
        List headerValues=new ArrayList();

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    try {
    setConnection(appDB);

    String queryName="SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES where table_name='table_name'";

    Reporter.addStepLog("----------------------------------- " + queryName.toUpperCase()
            + "\n - Validation Start" + " -----------------------------------");
    ps = con.prepareStatement(queryName, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("employedb");
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from all_tab_columns where table_name='table_name'"); 
      XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
      XSSFCell cell;
      int cc=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      for(int i=1;i<=cc;i++)
      {
          String headerVal=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
          headerValues.add(headerVal);
          cell = row.createCell(i-1);
          cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
      }
      System.out.println(headerValues);
      int i = 1;
      while (resultSet.next())
      {  
          for(int j=1;j<=cc;j++)
          {  
          System.out.println(resultSet.getString(j));
          XSSFRow row1 = spreadsheet.createRow((short) i);
          row1.createCell((short) i).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(j)));
          i++;

      }  
      }

      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("S:\\Downloads\\excel.xlsx"));
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();  
      System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");

}catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above issue got resolved.

```
public static void excel(String appDB)
{
    List<String> headerValues=new ArrayList<String>();

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    try {
    setConnection(appDB);

    String queryName="SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES where table_name='table_name";

    Reporter.addStepLog("----------------------------------- " + queryName.toUpperCase()
            + "\n - Validation Start" + " -----------------------------------");
    ps = con.prepareStatement(queryName, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("employedb");
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from all_tab_columns where table_name='table_name'");


      XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
      XSSFCell cell;
      int cc=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      for(int i=1;i<=cc;i++)
      {
          String headerVal=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
          headerValues.add(headerVal);
          cell = row.createCell(i-1);
          cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
      }
      System.out.println(headerValues);

      int i = 1;
      while (resultSet.next())
      {  

          XSSFRow row1 = spreadsheet.createRow((short) i);
          for(int p=0;p<headerValues.size();p++)
          {
          row1.createCell((short) p).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(headerValues.get(p)));
          }
          i++;
      } 
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("S:\\Downloads\\excel.xlsx"));
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();  
      System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");

}catch(Exception e){}
}
```