# How can I save the saved column of Entity class to Excel?

Tags: java, excel, spring, jpa, export-to-excel

How can I save the saved column of Entity class to Excel?

I want to create a Util class, and when Util class receive an Entity as parameter, I want to save the column stored in the Entity to Excel.

I was wondering how can I save different columns of multiple Entity in one Util class to Excel?

Comment: You need to take a look to Apache Poi and some for-loops.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933868/exporting-resultset-from-java-database-to-excel-using-apache-poi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting Resultset from Java database to Excel using Apache Poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933868/exporting-resultset-from-java-database-to-excel-using-apache-poi)